# @TransactionalEventListener(fallbackExecution = true) runs before commit

Tags: java, spring, events, asynchronous, transactions

I have a `@Service` class that runs some logic in a Spring `@Transactional` method.

That method "completes" a Process by setting the isCompleted flag to true.

It then updates the Process in the database and launches a ProcessCompletedEvent.

An **asynchronous** ProcessCompletedEventListener annotated with `@TransactionalEventListener(fallbackExecution = true)` picks up the launched ProcessCompletedEvent, and, if the number of completed Processes is equal to one, performs some additional logic.

Here is some sample code:

```
@Service
public class ProcessService {

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public Process completeProcess(Process process) throws ServiceException {

        process.setCompleted(true);
        process = processDao.update(process);

        eventPublisher.publishEvent(new ProcessCompletedEvent(process));

        return process;
    }
}

@Component
public class ProcessCompletedListener {

    @TransactionalEventListener(fallbackExecution = true)
    public void doStuffWhenFirstProcess(ProcessCompletedEvent event) {

        Process process = event.getProcess();

        //Thread.sleep(1000) <- Uncomment this, and everything works
        if (processService.getNumberOfCompletedProcesses(process.getUser()) == 1) {

            doStuff();

        }
    }
```

In my unit test, I run this with a new User that has no completed Processes.  In theory, when `completeProcess()` is called with this User, `doStuff()` should get called by the listener since this User now has exactly one completed process.

The issue is that when there is no Transaction (completeProcess() finished and closed Transaction), everything works fine.  However, when there is a transaction, `processService.getNumberOfCompletedProcesses(process.getUser())` returns `0`.  This is presumably because the Transaction that updates the Process to completed has not been committed yet.

However, with the default phase being AFTER_COMMIT, this should not be the case.  The Listener should wait until the transaction is committed and then run.  In that case the test should always pass.

For what it's worth, I am using `SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster` for Async event processing.  That is all working as expected with event listeners spawning in new Threads.

I have exhausted all possibilities, and I am very worried that their is a defect in the Spring @TransactionalEventListener.  I thought I would give you guys a chance to point something out before I submit a bug report to Spring.  Much thanks in advance!

Comment: For the record, the reporter has cross-posted on [the Spring Issue tracker](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-15943)